# How to disable the button when item are not checked?

Tags: javascript

I have multiple checkbox items which are associated to a button click event. But I am trying to disable the button when none of the check box item are checked. Here is my code:

```
    <script>

    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $('#cbOne').click(function(){

            if($(this).attr('checked') == false){
                $('#target-group').attr("disabled","disabled");
            }
            else {
                $('#target-group').click(function() {
                    var targetGroups = $("input:checkbox:checked", ".actors-$i").map(function() {
                        return $(this).val();
                    }).get();

                    $('#out').append(targetGroups.join(','));

                });
            }
        });


    });
</script>

<button class="aui-button" id="target-group" style="float: right">Generate Target Group</button>
```

Code works fine but button is enabled even when no checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`$('#target-group').attr("disabled", true);`

If that doesn't work try:

`$('#target-group').prop("disabled", true);`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#target-group').click(function() {
        if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        var targetGroups = $("input:checkbox:checked", ".actors-$i").map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();

        $('#out').append(targetGroups.join(','));

    });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/94zav0jt/)

Comment: I want the button itself to be disabled and should get enabled when the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //To check whether the checkbox is checked or not
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () 
    {
        if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
            $("#target-group").show();
        }
        else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
            $("#target-group").hide();
        }
    }
});
```